# Strategies for near real-time analytics

Tags: real-time, data-warehouse, olap, dimensional-modeling

I have few different "dimensions", mainly hierarchical I'd like to run some metrics saved at individual levels in hierarchy. As you're navigating through this hierarchical structure the metrics update depending on your current selection.

In traditional OLAP systems you'd have some dimension tables with a fact table and you do an ETL to get data into your data warehouse and run the queries against that. I'd like to do this near real-time. Doing this real-time means ETLs have to be run in near real-time basis (probably data points cached in memory).

If the hierarchical structure is (X -> Y -> Z), then if I have 5 Xs, 2 Ys and 5 Zs as dimension then I need to run (5 * 2 * 5) => 50 queries to get fact table populated? If this hierarchy grows bigger then I can easily get into running millions of queries. I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this problem correctly, it would greatly help if someone with real time data analytics experience can share their experience.

Comment: I think this would be a lot easier to understand if you could explain the actual table structure - are X, Y, and Z separate Dimension tables? Or a hierarchy built into one Dimension table? Real names and information on how they relate would help as well. I don't understand the 50 queries or potential millions of queries bit at this point, but I suspect with that kind of information it would get a lot clearer!

Answer (score -1):

Do not understand why you'd need millions of queries to update your facts data. A simple 'incremental-id' per table could say to the OLAP system which rows needs to be loaded each time the data needs to be refreshed.

Perhaps you can have a look to [icCube](http://www.iccube.com/binary-com-case-study-real-time-analysis/) that allows for near [real-time](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/walkthrough/walkthrough_rt.php) analytics; as the cubes do not cache any aggregation, each time new data has been loaded, it is ready for query.